# Filters in node js on timeperiod

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, node-modules

query.js

```
exports.getUser = async(userId, employeeStatus, department, firstName, timePeriod) => {
if (timePeriod) {
    if (timePeriod = 'today') {
           ==> I Want here createdon that is having today's date rest working fine
    }
}
let queryFilters = {userId, employeeStatus, department, firstName, timePeriod}
if(userId) return await model.find({"_id":userId}).exec();
queryFilters = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(queryFilters));
console.log(queryFilters)
return await model.find(queryFilters).exec();
}
```

query is working fine. I Want if time period = today then i want to see createdOn having today's date, same if time period = last 6 month then createdOn having date in last 6 month from today. createdOn is field in user, Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand your question, but if timeStamp is in the form of `Date` then you can check if it is equal to the date today with the following code.

```
var timeStamp = (new Date)

if (timeStamp.getDate() === (new Date).getDate()) {

  console.log('the dates are both ' + timeStamp.getDate())

} else {

  console.log('the dates are not the same')

}
```

Comment: createdAt is current time which saves when new user registers

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand what you're looking for. 